# How do I detect PHP engine crashes?

Tags: php, linux, crash, yum

Several of my Linux servers applied security upgrades yesterday, and one was for libnsssysinit.so. Consequently, my PHP code running through Apache and/or long-running PHP daemon processes (which fork) required restarts before any cURL request could succeed. Ecommerce customers were affected the most.

However, it was not just a simple function call failure, which my code checks for. The processes completely crashed, with almost no logging recording the event even occurred. The logs only provided one hint, and only on one server out of the affected ones I've debugged:

```
/usr/bin/php: symbol lookup error: /usr/lib64/libnsssysinit.so: undefined symbol: PR_GetEnvSecure
```

I found [a recent bug report](https://bugs.centos.org/view.php?id=12935) where the reporter(s) were instructed to just restart the affected processes (httpd in their case). That resolved it for me, too. BUT how can I have automatic security upgrades without them knowing my processes need to be restarted?

I understand I can mitigate this by logging proper application shutdowns and adding a watchdog to comb the logs. But is there a better way? Any built-in kernel/OS feature that can log/react when any process with my program's name abnormally terminates?

Comment: This might fair better on http://serverfault.com/ ?

Comment: I considered that, but I'm also willing to code the solution into my application, and I was wondering if PHP has any hooks to gracefully handle non-script crashes. OS solutions are welcome, though.

Comment: A daemon running a process should have its own log, normally in `/var/log/daemon-name/`. If not, and you are running a standard linux OS, logging should be available in `/var/log/messages`. Give more info about what OS, what version of `php` ?